# Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, django, axios, fetch-api, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to fetch some data from the Django Rest API. But browser throw cors policy error.

```
let headersList = {Accept: '*/*'}
fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: headersList,
     })
     .then(function (response) {
        return response.json()
      })
     .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data)
      })
```

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch 
the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I also include cors-header in django api.

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```